# checked radio pelo name e value javascript

Tags: javascript, radiobutton

Preciso marcar um dos inputs radio com `checked` via javascript, de preferência usando `name` e/ou `value` para isto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="generoi1" value="female">Feminino<br>
<input type="radio" name="generoi1" value="male">Masculino<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var lis = document.getElementByName("generoi1");
    lis.length;
    lis[0].checked = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como assim **checar** um input radio?

Comment: deixa o radio com checked = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é erro de digitação, não existe `getElementByName`, falta um S, o correto é `getElementsByName`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="generoi1" value="female">Feminino<br>
<input type="radio" name="generoi1" value="male">Masculino<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var lis = document.getElementsByName("generoi1");
    lis.length;
    lis[0].checked = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

O `lis[0]` vai pegar o primeiro elemento que encontrar e `lis[1]` vai pegar o segundo e assim por diante, pois o indice começa do zero.

Você pode optar por usar `querySelector` que é semelhante aos seletores CSS (se já souber usar), que deve ficar assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="generoi1" value="female">Feminino<br>
<input type="radio" name="generoi1" value="male">Masculino<br>

<button onclick="myFunction('female')">Feminino</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('male')">Masculino</button>


<script>
function myFunction(tipo) {
    var escolhido = document.querySelector("input[name=generoi1][value=" + tipo + "]");
    if (escolhido) {
       escolhido.checked = true;
    } else {
       alert('Elemento não encontrado');
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nossa... nem tinha visto

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: @lucaspereira editei a resposta com uma sugestão mais simples, se resolveu por favor marque a resposta como correta, se não souber como veja esse pequeno turotial de como usar o site: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635 - Obrigado!